# Deploy BlackBerry application to device

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have set the MIME type for jad, jar, and cod files on my web server.

After downloading the jar on a device, it shows me an error:
`invalid jar descriptor not found.`

I think there is a problem in the jad.

How do I deploy an eclipse blackberry application to a device? Which file do I have to download -- cod, jad or jar?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely is a problem in your .jad file, probably you are missing some attribute maybe "MIDlet-Jar-URL:".

for deployment you have to download the .jad file but in the same folder you must have the .cod (or .cod files)
the be sure if your .cod file is actually multiple cods rename to the .cod file to .zip and try to extract.

[Sibling CODS or how to make your App Install over the air](http://thinkingblackberry.com/?p=214)